# Google maps Waypoints and Direction in nativescript with Angular2

Tags: angular, google-maps, nativescript

Is it possible to render directions using waypoints like here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Is there any plugin to do this or any pointers in this direction will be helpful.

nativescript-google-maps-sdk doesn't support this I think and nativescript-directions just has directions from point a to b, does not support many points.

Answer (score 0):

in fact there is ANOTHER google-sdk plugin that does it, but I couldn't make it work 'cause it conflicts with Firebase plugin. Also it seems it is not supported anymore, but if you're good with plugins, maybe you can wire some functions...

https://github.com/mobilemindtec/nativescript-google-maps-sdk

If you manage to make it work, please let me know how!